# Joomla Jreviews Notice: Array to string conversion in components\com_jreviews\jreviews\models\menu.ph

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have the following error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\xampp\htdocs\reviews\components\com_jreviews\jreviews\models\menu.php on line 499
Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\xampp\htdocs\reviews\components\com_jreviews\jreviews\models\menu.php on line 503
```

Any one knows how to resolve this issue in joomla jreviews?

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution on this,

We need to put bellow modifications in file E:\xampp\htdocs\reviews\components\com_jreviews\jreviews\models\menu.php on line number 486 change the bellow line

$cat_id = $params['0'];

change above with bellow lines,

$cat_id = is_array($params['0'])?$params['0']['cat_id']:$params['0'];

**Thanks,**

## Nilesh G. Pangul